# Automatic label formulas with (*) and (**) instead of numbers

Tags: equations, numbering

As in the title, I would like to label formulas in certain environments (such as proofs) using (*), (**), ... instead of numbering. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: `\tag{*}` should work

Comment: How about an automated solution? I do not want to keep track of the number of * for the next label.

Comment: This could get really long ;-)

Comment: Are you using [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)? What about the ambiguity of having two proofs, each with a `(*)`?

Comment: What package do you use to create your proofs?

Comment: Sounds like you could use a symbolic "roman" numeral system: `*`, `**`, `***`, `*+`, `+`, `+*`, `+**`, etc.  Better still, i, ii, iii, iv, v, vi, vii, etc.

Comment: Provided that you have less than 9 numbered equations in a proof, you could redefine the equation label as `\renewcommand{\theequation}{\fnsymbol{equation}}`

Comment: @Werner I am using amsmath *proof*'s. Typically I only need a couple of equations in a proof that needs labeling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

This works with `hyperref` even for multiple occurences of `**` (which is unclear,however, then) as long as the dummy proof counter `proof` isn't reset.

The equation number is expanded first before it's used in `\loopstars`.

Of course, this will provide trouble if there are more than 10 symbols, i.e. the equation 'number' will get too wide!

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newcounter{starcnt}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\loopstars}[1]{%
  \c@starcnt\z@%
  \loop\unless\ifnum\c@starcnt = #1%
  \advance \c@starcnt by \@ne%
  *%
  \repeat%
}
\makeatother

\newcounter{proof}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{proof}{%
  \refstepcounter{proof}%
  \renewcommand{\theHequation}{equation.\arabic{proof}.\arabic{equation}}
  \renewcommand{\theequation}{\protect\loopstars{\number\value{equation}}}
}

\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}

In \eqref{foo} we see that and in \eqref{foobar}


\begin{proof}
  \begin{equation}
    E=mc^2
    \end{equation}  
    \begin{align}
      E=mc^2 \label{foo} \\
      E=mc^2
 \end{align}    
\end{proof}

\clearpage
\setcounter{equation}{0}
\begin{proof}
  \begin{equation}
    E=mc^2
    \end{equation}  
    \begin{align}
      E=mc^2 \label{foobar} \\
      E=mc^2
 \end{align}    
\end{proof}
```

**Code Golfing ahead**

```
  \documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newcounter{starcnt}
\newcounter{proof}
\newcounter{dummycntr}

\newcommand{\mynumberingplaceholder}{$\int\!$}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\loopsymbols}[1]{%
  \raggedleft%
  \c@starcnt\z@%
  \loop\unless\ifnum\c@starcnt = #1%
  \advance \c@starcnt by \@ne%
  \mynumberingplaceholder%
  \repeat%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{proof}{%
  \refstepcounter{proof}%
  \renewcommand{\theHequation}{equation.\arabic{proof}.\arabic{equation}}
  \renewcommand{\theequation}{\protect\loopsymbols{\number\value{equation}}}
}

\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}

In \eqref{foo} we see that and in \eqref{foobar}


\begin{proof}
  \begin{equation}
    E=mc^2
    \end{equation}  
    \begin{align}
      E=mc^2 \label{foo} \\
      E=mc^2
    \end{align} 
    \loop\unless\ifnum\value{dummycntr} = 10
    \stepcounter{dummycntr}
    \begin{equation}
      c^2 = a^2 +b^2 \\
    \end{equation}  
    \repeat
\end{proof}

\clearpage
\setcounter{equation}{0}
\begin{proof}
  \begin{equation}
    E=mc^2
    \end{equation}  
    \begin{align}
      E=mc^2 \label{foobar} \\
      E=mc^2
 \end{align}    
\end{proof}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works really well. I adapted it to get different tagging commands; e.g. use (*) for exact sequences, and keep numbering for equations.

Comment: @AnHoa: What do you mean by `exact sequences`?

Comment: It is in widely used in homological algebra. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_sequence

Comment: Did you try doing *two* proof environments?

Comment: @egreg: Yes, in both examples there are two `proof` environments`. I've reset the equation counter (just for demonstration purposes) manually however. Of course, I would not use this 'numbering' style for myself.

Answer (score 2):

Building on Christian's ideas, here's a version that resets the equation number in the proofs and keeps the outer ones to the standard. It also allows changing (locally) the symbol in a given `proof` environment (default are asterisks).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,xpatch}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \stars #1
 {
  \prg_replicate:nn { \use:c { c@#1 } } { \l_anhoa_eqsym_tl }
 }
\tl_new:N \l_anhoa_eqsym_tl
\NewDocumentCommand{\seteqsymbol}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_anhoa_eqsym_tl { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\seteqsymbol{*} % initialize

\newcounter{saveequation}
\newcounter{proof}
\xapptocmd{\proof}
 {%
  \stepcounter{proof}%
  \setcounter{saveequation}{\value{equation}}%
  \setcounter{equation}{0}%
  \renewcommand{\theequation}{\stars{equation}}%
  \renewcommand{\theHequation}{\theproof.\arabic{equation}}%
 }{}{}
\xapptocmd{\endproof}
 {\setcounter{equation}{\value{saveequation}}}
 {}{}

\begin{document}

Here is an equation
\begin{equation}
a=b
\end{equation}

\begin{proof}
This is an important equation
\begin{equation}
0=0\label{a}
\end{equation}
Note that \eqref{a} together with
\begin{equation}
0=0
\end{equation}
ends the proof.
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}\seteqsymbol{\ensuremath{\vee}}
This is an important equation
\begin{equation}
0=0\label{b}
\end{equation}
Note that \eqref{b} together with
\begin{equation}
0=0
\end{equation}
ends the proof.
\end{proof}

Here is an equation
\begin{equation}
a=b
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]